# C# How can I Coppy All Things in RichTextBox?

Tags: ms-word, richtextbox, data-conversion

I have a richTextBox and I add text and image. Text are not the same color and font. I want to convert to all things for doc file. I am using this codes for this.

```
wordeaktar.Application wordapp = new wordeaktar.Application(); 
wordapp.Visible = true; 
wordeaktar.Document worddoc; 
object wordobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; 
worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Add(ref wordobj); 
wordapp.Selection.TypeText(richTextBox1.Text);
wordapp = null;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktOqT.png)

This is the image of my richTextBox. How can I do that?

Comment: `richTextBox1.SelectAll(); richTextBox1.Copy(); worddoc.Range().Paste();`. However if you simply `richTextBox1.SaveFile("...", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)`, Word will be perfectly happy with that.

Comment: You are the king!!!

Answer (score 0):

[@Gserg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg)'s Answer is right!

"*richTextBox1.SelectAll(); richTextBox1.Copy(); worddoc.Range().Paste();. However if you simply richTextBox1.SaveFile("...", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText), Word will be perfectly happy with that*. – [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg)"